# Using a singleton to send messages between any two classes

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns, singleton, global-variables

Is using a singleton to send messages between classes a good or bad idea?

One side of the communication registers as a listener (listening for a certain string or object, possibly with some parameters) and the other side sends messages. There can be multiple or no listeners for any message.

Using such a pattern means objects in different projects can communicate without having a reference to one another.

A case where this could be useful is sending all errors in an application to one object. You can easily send an error from any part of the application and the error manager can listen for any errors that have occurred.

What are the downsides to taking such an approach?

Problems that come to mind are globals make it hard to do testing and the possibility of unexpected consequences since anything in the app could be listening for an event and in completely unrelated projects.

Comment: Seems to me that you need publish subscribe design pattern for this scenario. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34316/Topic-based-Publish-Subscribe-design-pattern-imple

Answer (score 1):

For situations like that I like using the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and making the Event Dispatcher a Singleton.

[image]

Comment: I was going to recommend the same thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an Event Aggregator? Like the one provided by Prism. 
http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/

Using a Singleton is risky from unit testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Or...as another option [Mediator design patterm](http://www.dofactory.com/net/mediator-design-pattern). Since by concept it defines an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact. Mediator promotes loose coupling by keeping objects from referring to each other explicitly, and it lets you vary their interaction independently.

Regarding to

> make it hard to do testing

you can always consider mocking.